# Loopback mmsql aggregation,groupby

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, mssql-jdbc

I am using Loopback mssql connector in nodejs

Question: is there anyway to get aggregation, count function available in loopback ORM instead sql raw query?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my read of the docs, there is nothing built in to support this. You would need to add your own custom logic to your models to support this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. lodash/underscore packages are good to do aggregation. However, it will take more time. First to call find function with limited filter {}, later need to call aggregation functions. so any other fast way to process data?